# MS Word: change existing captions name

Tags: ms-word

this is my first post, so I would like to say hello :)

I have a very large document, it consists of ~150 captions.
I would like to change name of the captions, for example from 'Picture' to 'Pic.'
Is there any simple method to do it? I can't imagine changing all of the existing captions and cross-references manualy.

Best regards,
Michal

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Are you looking for a programmatic way of doing so?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 14):

Here is the way:

1. Select the caption with a number that has the label that you want to change.
   For example, if you have "Picture 1", select the entire caption including label, sequence number, and the caption text.
2. On the References tab, in the Captions group, click *Insert Caption*.
3. In the Label dropdown, select the label that you want or click *New Label* and add a new one.

Comment: This will only add an additional caption. OP wants to update existing captions without losing cross-references already in the document

Comment: Moved to MacOs recently, so can't double check it. However, I am almost sure that the first step in my algorithm ensures updating existing one. Because I was looking for the same thing back there and found this one, which is kind of not transparent. Have you tried doing this?

Comment: Tested this in Office 365 Pro+ last week and in step 2 it would just create a second caption inside of the text of the caption selected in step 1. But maybe I just put the cursor there, without making a selection around the entire caption. I will give this another try

Comment: One more thing may be behavior difference with Microsoft Word 2013 that I've used at that moment. But thank you for trying anyway. According to 4 upvotes, this thing worked at least on some versions.

Comment: And here is a similar answer on Microsoft forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-there-a-way-to-edit-existing-caption-label/3d3ad546-456a-425c-bcd2-964c01b16e01

I think I used it to update captions in my Thesis at university

Comment: I gave this another try and it did indeed work in Office 365 Pro+ as well now. I must've not done step 1 incorrectly.

Comment: This works for me with Word 2019 Professional Plus.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Works well on Word for Mac v.16 (Office 365 for Home)

Comment: I never thought it would work but it actually did! Seems very unintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found on Word Tips:
https://word.tips.net/T003888_Changing_Existing_Captions.html

"If you want to change some of the text in the captions, you need to modify the fields used to create the captions. (Automatic captions are implemented through the use of fields in the document.) You can change the text in the fields by first displaying the field codes in your document (press Shift+F9). You should be able to see what the field codes look like for your captions; examine one to see how it is constructed, looking specifically for the text you want to change.

Next press Ctrl+H to display the Replace tab of the Find and Replace dialog box. Use the controls in the dialog box to specify the caption text you want to change (from within the field you examined) and what you want the text to be. You can then use the controls to step through all the occurrences of the text and change it, as desired.

There are other things you can change in the fields using this same technique. For instance, you may want to change the numbering of your captions from Arabic to Roman. If you examine the field code used for a caption, it may appear similar to this:

{Seq Figure *\ arabic}

You can easily use the Find and Replace method to change the word "arabic" to "roman." When you are done making the changes, press Alt+F9 to change the field codes back to their results.

If your caption changing needs are a bit more complex (perhaps, for example, you want to change the caption to appear above a figure instead of below it, or vice-versa), then the best bet is to change the settings for automatic captions and then delete all the existing captions. You can then use cut and paste (cut the figure and paste it back in the same position) to force Word to automatically add the caption with the new settings."

Answer (score 1):

you can edit individual captions by using Outline view.

(Update) To clarify: to edit an existing table (or I assume figure) individual caption, open your word doc in Outline View and select the caption you'd like to change.

If you want to batch edit you may be able to use find/replace in Outline view to batch find/replace all.

(Caveat: I was not able to easily edit a table caption while in Print View, so tested Outline View and it worked.)

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your answer?

Comment: Edited main answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Find and Replace function changes both the cross references in the main text and in the captions.

Answer (score 0):

Insert new caption on References tab then replace old caption with new caption that you created, finally update whole table.